# Internal Domain Deployment throws an error

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I've been seeing this error for the last 24hrs when trying to re-publish my AddOn to my domain specific marketplace. When I first open the configuration tab, my version number seems to be missing. This was working previously. Now when I enter a version number and hit save I get this error.

[image: missing-version-number]

```
Sorry, there’s a problem. If you entered information, check it and try again. Otherwise, the problem might clear up on its own, so check back later.

Tracking Number: xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

No idea how to troubleshoot this so any guidance would be helpful. Im not really sure how to use the tracking number that is returned.

Comment: I am having the same issue. I am new to publishing add-ons so I'd be keen to know how often this happens.

Comment: It was working fine until late yesterday afternoon. Not sure if something changed on their end. Good to know that it's not just our add on.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to change version of my Google Sheets Add-on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60460924/unable-to-change-version-of-my-google-sheets-add-on)

Answer (score 1):

I work in the G Suite Marketplace. The issue has been fixed and it's rolling out to production between today and tomorrow.