# Unable to change version of my Google Sheets Add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-marketplace

I've made some bug fixes to a Google Sheets Add-on and now need to publish those changes. I've created a new version in my Script via File -> Manage versions. When I try to update my Add-on in the G Suite Marketplace SDK I get

> Error
>
> Sorry, there’s a problem. If you entered information, check it and try again.
>
> Otherwise, the problem might clear up on its own, so check back later.
>
> Tracking Number: 1747836347906634815

The only change we make is updating the version. This error has persisted for several days now and we really need to push this fix.

Comment: Go to the following link and click the star.  [https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150325704](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150325704)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upvote this issue:

- Google's issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150325704
- Google Support page: https://support.google.com/a/thread/31561936

Answer (score 0):

I work in the G Suite Marketplace. The issue has been fixed and it's rolling out to production between today and tomorrow.

Comment: The fix has been fully rolled out.