# G Suite Marketplace: At least one extension must be enabled and selected extensions must be configured

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-apps-marketplace, google-apps-script-addon

I have published an external Google Spreadsheets addon, and everything worked so far. Since a couple of days, within the "Google Cloud Platform > APIs & Services > G Suite Marketplace SDK > Configuration panel" the input field for "Sheets add-on script version" is empty and an error message "At least one extension must be enabled and selected extensions must be configured" is displayed.

I have already tried the following steps:

1. Insert the current published script version number and click "Save changes"
2. Insert a new script version number and click number and click "Save changes"

The response is the following:

> Error Sorry, there’s a problem. If you entered information, check it
>   and try again. Otherwise, the problem might clear up on its own, so
>   check back later.
>
> Tracking Number: 7178656512110690803
>
> Send feedback

The problem did not clear up so far and also the Google Support team did not reply to my feedback/message so far.

Due to this behaviour I am not able to publish new versions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to change version of my Google Sheets Add-on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60460924/unable-to-change-version-of-my-google-sheets-add-on)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work in the G Suite Marketplace. This issue has been fixed and it will roll out to production between today and tomorrow.

Comment: Hey, per https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150325704 this still seems to be broken. Do you have any further updates? Nobody from Google seems to be responding to that thread.

Comment: A new version of the Cloud Console with a fix is being rolled out, it will be fully rolled out today.

Comment: The fix has been fully rolled out.

Answer (score 3):

It is a new bug. Please star the issue on [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150325704) for updates.